# Finding baseDomain in regex using php

Tags: php, regex

What i wanted to do is to search for `$BaseDomain` if it exist within the link match by regex and if true no need of opening the link in another tap. I also tried using `$replacePattern1` instead of `$1` and `$replacePattern2` instead of `$2`. The `target = _blank` is never appended to the `href` when the the link is not the `$BaseDomain`. Please where am i wrong?

```
function ReplaceUrlToHtmlLink($source) {
           /// my site name ///
            $BaseDomain = "ivotism.com";
    //URLs starting with http://, https://, or ftp://
    $replacePattern1 = '/(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/i';
    $source =  preg_replace($replacePattern1, '<a href="$1" ' . (strpos('$1', $BaseDomain) !== false ?
                    ' target="_blank"' : '') . '>$1</a>', $source);

    //URLs starting with "www." (without // before it, or it'd re-link the ones done above).
    $replacePattern2 = '/(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/i';
    $source =  preg_replace($replacePattern2, ' <a href="http://$2" ' . (strpos('$2', $BaseDomain) !== false ?
                    ' target="_blank"' : '') .'>$2</a>', $source);

    //Change email addresses to mailto:: links.
    $replacePattern3 = '/(([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.])+@[a-zA-Z\_]+?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+)/i';
    $source =  preg_replace($replacePattern3, '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>', $source);
     return $source;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `=== true` in all your tests. Because `!== false` work also for `0`.

But it is not possible to use $1 (or $n) in other function, even in the same line argument.

Use:

```
function ReplaceUrlToHtmlLink($source) {
    /// my site name ///
        $BaseDomain = "ivotism.com";    // or "ivotism\.com"

    //URLs starting with http://, https://, or ftp://
    $replacePattern1 = '/(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/i';
    $source =  preg_replace($replacePattern1, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $source);

    //URLs starting with "www." (without // before it, or it'd re-link the ones done above).
    $replacePattern2 = '/(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/i';
    $source =  preg_replace($replacePattern2, ' <a href="http://$2" target="_blank">http://$2</a>', $source);

    //Change link with domain.
    $replacePattern3 = '/(<a href="[^"]+'. $BaseDomain .'[^"]*") target="_blank">/i';
    $source =  preg_replace($replacePattern3, '$1>', $source);

    //Change email addresses to mailto:: links.
    $replacePattern4 = '/(([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.])+@[a-zA-Z\_]+?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+)/i';
    $source =  preg_replace($replacePattern4, '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>', $source);
     return $source;
}
```

Comment: I have done that, but does not work. Any hint again?

Comment: `$1` can not be used any variable starting with a number in PHP, and I used "$1" too but does not work.

Comment: Sorry for my too quick and wrong answer. I corrected.

Comment: No problem! But now the `target=_blank` attribute is assigned when it is the `$BaseDomain`, instead of when it is not the `basedomain`

Comment: I want to open any other link in a new tap apart from the link that contains baseDomain

Comment: Its your day really! **I wish i can reward!**

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help a little.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to make a clean and relatively robust function that parses the text only once.

I have voluntarily used naive subpatterns to describe the part from the hostname to the end of the URL *(i.e. `\S+(?<=[\PP#?/&])`)* and to describe the email *(i.e. `[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+`)* that are obviously too permissive. So feel free to improve them. However, keep in mind that the goal of the pattern is to extract, not to validate. The validation tasks are assigned in parts to `parse_url` and to `filter_var`:

```
define ('BASE_DOMAIN', 'ivotism.com');
define ('DEFAULT_SCHEME', 'http');

function createLinks ($text) {
    $pattern =  '~
      (?=[hsfw/])     # quick check
      (?:             # start with scheme or //
          (?:
              \b (?<scheme> https? | s?ftp | ftps? ) :
            |
              (?<=\s|\A) # when there is no scheme, slashes
                         # must be preceded by a whitespace
          )
          (?<slashes> // )
          (?: www\. )?
        |             # OR start with "www."
          \bwww\.
      )
      \S+             # non-whitespace characters
      (?<=[\PP#?/&])  # last character allowed
    |
      (?<mail> [^\s@]+ @ [^\s@]+ )
    ~ix';

    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) {
        if (isset($m['mail'])) {
            if (filter_var($m['mail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                return '<a href="mailto:' . $m['mail'] . '">' . $m['mail'] . '</a>';
            return $m[0];   
        } else {
            $url = (empty($m['scheme']) ? DEFAULT_SCHEME . ':' : '')
                 . (empty($m['slashes']) ? '//' : '') . $m[0];
            $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);

            if (empty($host) || preg_match('~(?:\A|\.)\Q'. BASE_DOMAIN . '\E\z~i', $host))
                return $m[0];

            return '<a href="'. $url . '" target="_blank">' . $url . '</a>';
        } 
    }, $text);
}
```

Comment: In this scenario, if the url start with www without http, 'location' can not be use to redirect it. In the real code,  '?' is appended in 'href=' to enable the url be treated as a get variable,  the header location is used to redirect.